# Breezejs, Browser freezes while manager assemples the objects

Tags: javascript, breeze

I have the following problem:

- Breeze fetches metadata (23.4KB)
- Breeze fetches lookups (4.5MB)

Right after lookups are downloaded, the browser will become unresponsive for about 30 seconds.
After this, everything works like a charm.

Why does breeze not use timeouts to inform the UI?

Firefox complains about long script operation, unresponsive, etc. The task manager (shows Firefox/Chrome/etc) as unresponsive.

Am I doing something wrong, or this is by design?

If this is by design, can i use a 'Web Worker' to do all the heavy operations and then return the whole model or something?

Comment: "Breeze fetches lookups (4.5MB)" Sounds like an insane amount of lookups.  I would guess you are fetching over 100k records just in lookups and then Breeze has to map all of the related properties of those lookups.  Have you thought about reducing that to only what is needed?

Comment: Of course, thought this is what i need.
It's something like the admin tool for a web app. 

I don't expect to be faster, i expect it to be responsive since the databinding haven't yet initialized

Comment: http://windyroad.com.au/2007/03/30/web-apps-the-new-single-threaded-gui/

Even with a simple setTimeout is IS responsive

Comment: Yes the impression is enough so the user will not get an application is not responding dialog.

I am not looking for Full responsiveness, multithreads.
All i need is something to avoid the not responding, which can be accomplished somehow like the previous link i posted.

Comment: Breeze is not related to SPA.

Comment: From the Breeze.js website - "BreezeJS is a pure JavaScript library for building Single Page Applications in HTML and JavaScript. "

Comment: Sir, please if you cannot help stop making useless comments.

The question was simple, can i use breeze without the unresponsiveness resulting from the huge ammount of entities creation.

Either i go SPA or multiple pages the same problem will continue to exist, if i keep using Breeze.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried something like this:

```
var test = function (name) {
        return Q.fcall(function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                toastr.success(name); // Notify me
                return EntityQuery.from(name)
                      .using(manager).execute()
            }, 1000) // This should be zero
        });
    };

    var primeData = function (name) {
        return test('Languages')
                .then(test('dummy1'))
                .then(test('dummy2'))
                .then(test('dummy3'))
                .then(test('dummy4'))
    };
```

However the notifications seem to be poping up all at the same time, indicating that

```
return EntityQuery.from(name)
                      .using(manager).execute()
```

does not return when entity constuction finishes but when the JSON data for this entity arrived.

***EDIT***
Answer with webWorker provided here : [BreezeJs with dedicated web worker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22132304/breezejs-with-dedicated-web-worker)

Answer (score 0):

I think  I see your point. Breeze hogs the UI thread while processing  those thousands of arriving entities. If Breeze could somehow realize how much work it was doing, and would be doing, it could throw a timeout in there to give the UI a chance to breathe.

I'm not sure how safe that would be as Breeze would have to pick a moment that didn't leave the cache in an unstable state from someone's perspective.

I believe you can make this easier on yourself by breaking the one giant Lookups call into several smaller ones. You could still async await completion of all the smaller lookup promises if that is critical to your app. The fact that they are independent promise callbacks should give you the relief you seek.

Please try that and let us know how it works for you.

P.S.: You also have a cool opportunity here to optionally cache these lookups in local storage (indexdb) so you don't have to download them everytime. You'd need a versioning scheme of course and some plumbing so this lies in your future once things are looking good.