# BreezeJs with dedicated web worker

Tags: javascript, requirejs, breeze, web-worker, q

I am trying to initialize a Breeze manager inside a 'Web Worker'.

RequireJs, knockout, q, breeze are being imported inside the worker.
After a call to:`EntityQuery.from('name').using(manager).execute()`,
the following error appears:
 `Uncaught Error: Q is undefined. Are you missing Q.js? See https://github.com/kriskowal/q`.

A live preview is uploaded here http://plnkr.co/edit/meXjKa?p=preview
(plunk supports downloading for easier debug).

*EDIT* -- relevant  code
**Worker.js**

```
importScripts('knockout.js', 'q.js', 'breeze.js', 'require.js');
define('jquery', function () { return jQuery; });
define('knockout', ko);
define('q', Q); //Just trying to assign q since breeze requests Q as q
require(function () {
var self = this;
this.q = this.Q; //Just trying to assign q since breeze requests Q as q

breeze.NamingConvention.camelCase.setAsDefault();
var manager = new breeze.EntityManager("breeze/Breeze");

var EntityQuery = breeze.EntityQuery;

// Q or q here is defined (TESTED)

var test = function (name) {
    return EntityQuery.from(name)
          .using(manager).execute()  // <-- Here q/Q breaks (I think on execute)
};

var primeData = function () {
    return test('Languages')
            .then(test('Lala'))
            .then(test('Lala2'))
};

primeData();
setTimeout(function () { postMessage("TestMan"); }, 500);
});
```

Worker will be initialized on main page as:

```
var myWorker = new Worker("worker.js");
```

Comment: Please put the relevant code in the question, not on some external platform.

Comment: Actually please put your code in some external platform like a fiddle or a plunkr so we can see it in action.

Comment: Hmm, ok read the question first and then post please..
The plunkr link was provided from the begining.

Anyway i solved the problem and got breeze fully working on a WebWorker.

I will post the solution tomorrow as soon as i get my hands on my PC

Comment: @BeStelios I know - I did read the question and I am working on your plunkr...  The other guy said not to do that, but it is helpful in helping you find the issue.  If you have fixed the problem consider posting an answer so others may find value in the future.

Comment: Stop working on the plunkr, it is way more complex.. :)
It requires an ajax-only Jquery, changes to require, and more.
These libs are using reference to window which is missing from the worker.

Full answer will be posted tommorow as i said.

Comment: BeStelios - I FEEL your pain. jQuery is one big ball of mud. Looking forward to your findings. Oh ... yes ... a plunkr beats pasted in code every time! Thanks for trying that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok here it goes:

1. Create a new requireJs and edit the
   `isBrowser = !!(typeof window !== 'undefined' && typeof navigator !== 'undefined' && window.document)`
   to
   `isBrowser = false`
2. Create a new Jquery so it uses nothing related to window and generally anything that a WebWorker cannot access. Unfortunatelly i can't remember where i got this Custom JQueryJs but i have uploaded it here "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/48132252/jqueydemo.js".
   Please if you find the author or the original change link and give credit.
3. My workerJs file looks like:

   ```
   importScripts('Scripts/test.js', 'Scripts/jqueydemo.js', 'Scripts/q.js', 'Scripts/breeze.debug.js', 'Scripts/require2.js');
   define('jquery', function () { return jQuery; });
   require(
   {
       baseUrl: "..",
   },
   function () {
   var manager = new breeze.EntityManager("breeze/Breeze");
   var EntityQuery = breeze.EntityQuery;
   var primeData = function () {
       return EntityQuery.from(name)
               .using(manager).execute()  // Get my Data
               .then(function (data) {
                   console.log("fetced!\n" + ((new Date()).getTime()));
                   var exportData = manager.exportEntities(); // Export my constructed entities
                   console.log("created!\n" + ((new Date()).getTime()));
                   var lala = JSON.stringify(exportData)
                   postMessage(lala); // Send them as a string to the main thread 
               })
   };
   primeData();
   });
   ```
4. Finally on my mainJs i have something like:

   ```
       this.testWorker = function () {
       var myWorker = new Worker("worker.js"); // Init Worker

       myWorker.onmessage = function (oEvent) { // On worker job finished
           toastr.success('Worker finished and returned');
           var lala = JSON.parse(oEvent.data); // Reverse string to JSON
           manager.importEntities(lala);  // Import the pre-Constructed Entities to breezeManager
           toastr.success('Import done');
           myWorker.terminate();
       };
   };
   ```

So we have managed to use breeze on a WebWorker enviroment to fetch and create all of our entities, pass our exported entities to our main breeze manager on the main thread(import).

I have tested this with 9 tables fully related to each other and about 4MB of raw data.

> *PROFIT*:  UI stays fully responsive all the time.
>   No more long execution script, application not responding or out of memory errors) at least for chrome

*As it makes sense breeze import entities is way more faster than the creation a full 4MB raw data plus the association process following for these entities.
By having all the heavy work done on the back, and only use import entities on the front, breeze allows you to handle large datasets '*like a breeze*'.

Comment: Very cool, I want to try this.  Have you tried using
 `manager.exportEntities(null, { asString: false, includeMetadata: false })`?  You shouldn't have to stringify the entities, unless there's some restriction on the postMessage implementation.